# R: LPsolve (linear programming) with "missing values"

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm trying to run LP in R (LPsolve) but where one of my combinations should never happen. If, for example, I'm trying to mate males and females (not humans :-)) to maximize a function value (matrix called "rank" below). However, one of the males is a full brother to one of the female so I don't want that mating to ever ever occur (say male 1 & female 1 in the matrix below). I want all the females mated (i.e., a constraint) and I want all the males to have 2 and only 2 matings (another constraint). I've tried making the [1,1] mating really negative and that can help but I want it to be fool proof. I've tried NA, NULL etc but to not avail.
Thanks in advance

```
rank <- matrix (0,3, 6) # matrix of males (rows) x females (columns) with the value to maximize for each combination

for (i in 1:3)  {
 for (j in 1:6) 
    {
     rank[i,j] <-i*j
    }
}


m <- NROW(rank)  #number of males
f <- NCOL(rank)  # number of females

row.signs <- c(rep("=", m)) 
row.rhs <- c(rep(2,m))
col.signs <- rep ("=", f) 
col.rhs <- c(rep(1,f))

lp.transport (rank, "max", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)$solution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can define that constraint using the default transportation problem formulation...
I suggest you to define the transportation problem by hand and then add your exclusions constraint :

```
library(lpSolve)
m <- 3 # n of males
f <- 6 # n of females
# rank matrix
rank <- matrix(1:(m*f),nrow=m)
# sibling exclusions (where the matrix is 1, we don't allow mating for that combination)
# here we block male 1 with female 1
exclusions <- matrix(0,nrow=m,ncol=f)
exclusions[1,1] <- 1
# transportation problem definition
obj <- as.numeric(rank)
nMalePerFemaleRhs <- rep(1,f)
nMalePerFemaleSign <- rep("=",f)
nMalePerFemaleConstr <- matrix(0,nrow=f,ncol=m*f)
for(i in 1:f){
  nMalePerFemaleConstr[i,(i-1)*m+(1:m)] <- 1
}
nFemalePerMaleRhs <- rep(2,m)
nFemalePerMaleSign <- rep("=",m)
nFemalePerMaleConstr <- matrix(0,nrow=m,ncol=m*f)
for(i in 1:m){
  nFemalePerMaleConstr[i,seq(from=i,length.out=f,by=m)] <- 1
}
# sibling exclusions constraint
siblingConstr <- t(as.numeric(exclusions))
siblingRhs <- 0
siblingSign <- '='

res <- lp(direction='max',
          objective.in=obj,
          const.mat = rbind(nMalePerFemaleConstr,nFemalePerMaleConstr,siblingConstr),
          const.dir = c(nMalePerFemaleSign,nFemalePerMaleSign,siblingSign),
          const.rhs = c(nMalePerFemaleRhs,nFemalePerMaleRhs,siblingRhs),
          all.int = TRUE
          )
solutionMx <- matrix(res$solution,nrow=m)
```

Result :

```
> solutionMx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
```